# Displaying and hiding update fields in shopping cart using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following piece of code:

```
<span>2</span><button onClick="//show quantity_update form">edit</button> 
<div id="qty_update" class="hidden">
 <form method="post">
   <input type="number" />
   <button type="submit" >update</button>
 </form>
</div>
```

So, when my page loads, the quantity_update form divs are not visible.

I want to show the div when I click on the edit button.

I'm struggling to figure out how to "link" the quantity_update div and the edit button, so that I don't show all the divs on the line items when I click on one of the quantity edit buttons.

So for instance this piece of code would not work:

```
$('.hidden').removeClass('hidden');
```

Because that makes all the hidden divs visible.

If I could somehow maybe have the id of the edit button and the div increment in some way, and then do some magic to figure out which div to show, I think that would help.  But I don't know how to do that.

Comment: As I understand, you mean you have rows, and each row has a edit button , and you need to show the "quantity update" div of only that row. Am I right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose both the span and div inside another div. Add a class to the button. Then you can do something like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.myButton').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().find(".hidden").removeClass('hidden');
    });
});
```

Though I must say, instead of removing the class outright, you might consider just setting the display/visible property. In that case, you could change the property because you can still access the element with the class name. Removing the class altogether might leave you with nothing to find the div.

Comment: Thanx, Anudeep!  You're solution works perfectly.  I wasn't planning on using the "hidden" class to find the div.  It was just the first thing that jumped into my mind when I asked the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$('#qty_update').removeClass('hidden');
```

i.e. work on the individual id, not all the hidden classes.

Note that normally you wouldn't use the onClick event in the html code when using jQuery. Instead you'd set a handler for the click event in the `$(document).ready(function() {...});` function. Like:

In your html, add an id to the button:

```
<button id="myButton1">
```

Then in your `<script>` section add:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myButton1').click(function() {
        $('#qty_update').removeClass('hidden');
    });
});
```

Comment: I can't use #qty_update because there might be 20 jobs in the shopping cart, then I have 20 divs with the same id.  So, I need a way to make unique id's and keep track of them (I think).

Comment: Sorry - I don't understand what you're trying to do when you click edit? Could you show a bit more html with (say) 2 jobs in the cart.

Comment: As Anudeep Bulla said: '...you mean you have rows, and each row has a edit button, and you need to show the "quantity update" div of only that row.'